# GWT Time Picker?

Tags: gwt

Does anyone know if in GWT we have a good TimePicker ?
In fact I want a widget in order to select hour and minute for GWT.

Thanks

Answer (score 17):

AFAIK there's no such a widget. Also "a good TimePicker" is a bit suggestive. I've been looking for such a widget for a long time and I found some javascript examples that were completely awful, but some people is using.

Finally I decided to do my own, based in a TextBox with value control.

[image]

The source code is available, you can find more info [here](http://ctasada.blogspot.com.es/2012/04/gwt-eureka-available.html) and on [github](http://github.com/ctasada/GWT-Eureka) I hope you like it.

I have seen some TimePicker that are simple ComboBoxes.

Comment: Hi Carlos, 
you're Timepicker sounds great
Do you have a demo somewhere?

Comment: @scraly: Not yet, I'll probably publish something in my blog after Xmas

Comment: Yes, could you please share it ? :)

Comment: I'm finishing a refactoring of the whole widget. I'm planning to publish it in github during the next week. I'll inform as soon is ready.

Comment: The source code is available, you can find more info here: http://ctasada.blogspot.com.es/2012/04/gwt-eureka-available.html and here https://github.com/ctasada/GWT-Eureka
I hope you like it.

Comment: Great work! Any chance you can show how to put this in a celltable cell?

Comment: @iliask: I'll add some example in GitHub during the next days

Answer (score 9):

I know this question was asked a while ago, but I came across it during my search for a GWT time picker and I decided to write my own.

[image: Picture of UTCTimeBox]

It supports many different input formats (4p => 4:00pm, 745 => 7:45am, etc) and has a drop-down menu with times at fixed intervals.

On iOS, it automatically uses an HTML5 input type="time"

[image]

[Blog article describing the implementation](http://traction.tractionsoftware.com/traction/permalink/Blog1986)

[Demo of the UTCTimeBox](http://gwt-traction.googlecode.com/hg/demo/com.tractionsoftware.gwt.demo.utctimebox.UTCTimeBoxDemo/UTCTimeBoxDemo.html)

[Demo of the UTCDateBox and UTCTimeBox being used together](http://gwt-traction.googlecode.com/hg/demo/com.tractionsoftware.gwt.demo.utcdatetime.UTCDateTimeDemo/UTCDateTimeDemo.html)

[Download at Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-traction/)

Answer (score 5):

[GWT Bootstrap](http://gwtbootstrap.github.com/#component%3adatetimepicker) GWT widget library has a nice date+time widget, along with many other solid widgets.

[http://gwtbootstrap.github.com/#component:datetimepicker](http://gwtbootstrap.github.com/#component%3adatetimepicker)

Edit: Looks like there is newer version available for bootstrap 3.

Comment: looks like the way to go for me, thanks for the comment, i would just update it to https://github.com/gwtbootstrap3

Answer (score 4):

I created gwt-timepicker which is using the concept of jquery timepicker. It does exactly what you need (hour/minute). Take a look: http://code.google.com/p/gwt-timepicker/

check this post: http://www.summa-tech.com/blog/2011/03/21/gwt-timepicker/

Answer (score 1):

The gwt incubator has an alright [time picker](http://code.google.com/docreader/#p=google-web-toolkit-incubator&s=google-web-toolkit-incubator&t=Spinner)

The code would be something like the example given:

```
// A TimePicker with no "AM/PM" and no "seconds" field and using 24H formatting for "hours" field
TimePicker timePicker = new TimePicker(new Date(), null, DateTimeFormat.getFormat("HH"), DateTimeFormat.getFormat("mm"), null);
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a Time Picker recently. I wrote it in a hurry, so it's not the best out there, but it works fine.

It attempts to create a HTML5 `<input type="time"/>` and if it's not supported by the browser, it parses manually. I have tested it on Chrome and Firefox on PC, and iOS.

Accepted formats are:

- 12:59 AM
- 5 - assumed to be 5 AM
- 5p - 5:00 PM
- 13 - 1 PM
- 345 - 3:45 AM
- 1534 - 3:34 PM
- 111p - 1:11 PM

it implements `HasValue<Long>` to return the picked time as milliseconds. It also has a method to return the time combined with a given `Date` object.

Here's the source: https://github.com/srilankanchurro/gwt-stuff/blob/master/gwt-stuff/src/com/sathkumara/client/TimePicker.java

If you have modifications to contribute to this class, please feel free to send me a request on github.

Answer (score 0):

[DatePicker](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/datepicker/client/DatePicker.html) and [DateBox](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/datepicker/client/DateBox.html)

```
 DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker(); 

 DateBox dateBox = new DateBox();
```

Here is [GWT DatePicker example](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwDatePicker)

and you can format the datetime to your needs with [DateTimeFormat](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/DateTimeFormat.html) and here is [example](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwDateTimeFormat)

Comment: Could you give an example of how to edit Times with the DatePicker ?

Comment: you can setValue datePicker.setValue(new Date(), true); and you can give format to it

Comment: Thanks, but the "picker" is still for dates. And OP would have to deal with a DateTime rather than just a Time.

Comment: then, extend from it and change it to your needs. I mentioned that you have also have dateTimeFormatter

Comment: I'm sorry but OP is asking for at TimePicker and I can't see how you can end up with one by extending the DatePicker. The format only formats the displayed value in the DateBox, not the "picker" itself.

Answer (score 0):

GXT has a [TimeField](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/gxtdocs/com/extjs/gxt/ui/client/widget/form/TimeField.html) widget [Example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/GWT/UsingTimeFieldExtGWT.htm) Good or not it's your choice :)

Maybe you can give an eye to [DateTimePicker](https://github.com/ghuntley/Ext.ux.touch.DateTimePicker)
[image]https://github.com/ghuntley/Ext.ux.touch.DateTimePicker