# DateTime picker in GWT cell table?

Tags: gwt

I am uing GWT 2.4.In which i am using a cell table.
This is cell table has a column of date time type.This column is editable.I want to set a feature so that on click of the cell some kind of date time picker should open and whatever date and time selected by the user should be updated in the respective cell.

I have used datepicker cell for this but it is only for the date, not for the time.
If any body has an idea about how to get date time picker in gwt editable cell table please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509655/gwt-time-picker

Comment: @Hulk thanks for comment.But I want gwt date time picker in for of cell. So that I can use it in cell table.

Answer (score 2):

How about using the [DatePickerCell](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/cell/client/DatePickerCell.html) ?
The Cell Widget [showcase](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellSampler) should have an example + code.

Comment: It has only date picker not the time..I want date and time at the same time...or any other way to get it

Comment: You can create a ``CompositeCell`` with a ``DatePickerCell`` and a normal ``TextBoxCell``. Or you can try to subclass/extend the ``DatePickerCell`` and implement the functionality yourself.

Comment: Thanks for reply...that is my mind....thr is also an option of advance gwt datepicker...

Comment: I don't know about advanced gwt datepicker. However take into account that with the ``CellWidgets`` you can't just easily insert other GWT widgets in ``Cells`` (unlike ``FlexTable`` for example)