# Grid binding with other types than "string" or inline-edit with some datetimepicker

Tags: gwt, datetimepicker, gxt, uibinder, inline-editing

So I was trying to add grid binding to an already finished grid that has string and date values. Example: http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace:gridbinding

```
╔═════════╦═════════════════════╗
║  room   ║      date/time      ║
╠═════════╬═════════════════════╣
║ L1-0056 ║ 25.02.2014 06:23:16 ║
║ L2-0061 ║ 25.02.2014 08:54:31 ║
╚═════════╩═════════════════════╝
```

Room: ComboBox with room values

Date/Time: Either `DatePicker` + some self-made `TimePicker`, or some `DateTimePicker` library... (getting the gxt-datepicker to work was easy, but I also need to edit the time)

Getting the date values into the editor and vice versa doesn't seem to be the problem (aside from the fact that I also need to edit the time).

There isn't any `DateTimePicker` in gxt, right? So... how do I define 2 editor fields for one cell in a grid?

Also: using a `TextBox` to edit the string in the first column works fine, but how can I use a `ComboBox` as editor?

As an alternative, I used inline-editing: http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace:inlineeditablegrid

In this case, everything works fine. Except the fact, that I still cannot edit the time in the date field with given picker. Not sure what method to pick here (either inline editor or binding) - but on both I cannot figure out how to edit the time-part in the date field, any ideas?

Either one is fine, as long as I get the editing to work.

[edit] the datetime picker part may be answered (thanks :) ), gotta give it a try - any ideas about the combobox-binding?

Comment: +1 Nice ascii art for your table, did you make it by hand or do you have a tool for this?

Comment: http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [GWT Time Picker?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509655/gwt-time-picker)

Comment: nope, im not looking for a timepicker pre se. im looking for a combination of date and time. this twitter library bootstrap would do the job with the binding alternative, i guess (first example) - since i dont have any clue how to define a custom inline-editor for a datefield.

Comment: Well one solution would be to store the date and time as separate fields, then you could have a picker for each one, but I understand if that's not what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend GWT-Bootstrap's `DateTimePicker` at http://gwtbootstrap.github.io/#component:datetimepicker

It brings up a time picker after the date has been selected:

[image]

As you say, there doesn't seem to be an equivalent in GXT.

I'd say you are better off with one widget so if you don't want to use another 3rd-party library then you'll have to roll your own composite widget.

Comment: thanks. also with gwt-wrapper. alright, this would do the work with binding, if i went with the binding approach (not quite sure how to define this as inline-editor). maybe someone also has an idea about the combobox-binding?