# Is there a single DateTime Picker component for gwt?

Tags: java, date, datetime, gwt

I need to use a single date time picker component. Currently, I am using `DateBox` but I need to pick hours also. As far as I can see, with `DateBox` I can specify Input Date Format like `"MM/dd/yyyy/hh/mm"` and I can edit the hours and the minutes with the keyboard. But this is not what I want. I want to be able to choose the time with the mouse. And I dont want to have separate dropdown menu for the time, I want the date and the time to be one component. I couldn't find such a gwt component. Do I have to write it manually? Is there something similar, written for gwt that I can use? If not, what can I do in this case?

Comment: i think you can use this component itself in your gwt apps xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker wrap this in jsni and inject this jsni code to textbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://gwtbootstrap.github.io/#component:datetimepicker) picker might suit your needs, further answers can be found regarding this familiar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509655/gwt-time-picker).

Comment: I need to have some a possibility to pick/change the time with the mause. For this date/time picker, I can do this just with the keyboard. But thanks anyway!

Comment: Did you see the component under "DataTimeBox markup"? It lets you select both date and time by mouse.

Comment: yes, but these are two different text boxes that work together. What I need is something like this: http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/ (see the demo)